# Finding recurrence relations of an algorithm

Tags: recurrence, relation

I'm reading my algorithms text book, and I'm reading about recurrence relations and finding the algorithms big O complexity. I run across this line

```
"In the case of the merge-sort algorithm, we get the recurrence equation:

    t(n) = b                  if n < 2

         = 2t(n/2) +bn        if n >= 2

for b > 0
```

my response was "how the heck did we know that?!?!"

So i'm wondering if there is a systematic approach, or just a logical way of getting these recurrence relations from the algorithms

can some one explain where the b and the two 2's come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merge sort algorithm can be summarized as:

```
mergesort (array A) {
   mergesort (first half of A);
   mergesort (second half of A);
   merge the two halves and return;
}
```

There is an O(N) algorithm to merging two arrays of length N, i.e. its complexity is *bN* for some constant *b* > 0.

Assuming the complexity of `mergesort` is T(N). Since half of N is N/2, we see that:

```
mergesort (array A) {                    T(N)    =
   mergesort (first half of A);          T(N/2)  +
   mergesort (second half of A);         T(N/2)  +
   merge the two halves and return;       bN
}
```

which explains the N ≥ 2 case.

The N < 2 case (the base case where you stop the recursion) is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this statement is (presumably) the conclusion of a discussion, or at least a statement, of the algorithm in question. Without the details I can only made educated guesses, which would go like this:

- the first thing the algorithm does is check if it's being asked to process 0 or 1 elements. If that's true, it returns immediately. Thus, then `n < 2`, there is a fixed cost - call it `b`
- For `n >= 2`, the algorithm splits its input into two pieces, each of size `n/2`, and invokes itself on each piece. Each such invocation will have a cost of `t(n/2)`, and there are two such invocations
- There is then an additional cost to merge the two pieces back together - this cost will be proportional to `n` - call it `b` times `n`

The only slight oddity is that it's not entirely obvious why the two constant factors that arise should be the same - but part of the point of big-O analysis is that constant factors eventually don't matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
T(n) = c if n < d
     = A*T(n/b) + f(n)
```

where d>=1 and there are A subproblems and the subproblems are at most n/b size. f(n) is the total additional time needed to divide the problem into subproblems and merge the subproblem solutions into a solution to the entire problem.

this is for divide and conquer algorithms.

I wonder why there are 2 subproblems in merge sort?

Comment: Updates to your question should be made as edits to the question, rather than answers. To answer your query, look at the merge-sort algorithm that the text is talking about, and you will see that it makes *two* recursive calls to itself, thus *two* sub-problems.